# Javascript calling C# with multiple parameters

Tags: xamarin.forms, wkwebview

I used the following - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/ to implement a hybrid webview. All works fine expect the part where I need to call the C# function from Javascript. The C# handler gets called but from the article, it seems like I can only get a single parameter passed to C#. So message.Body.ToString() gives me the arguments passed from Javascript. I however want to pass atleast to arguments. Can anybody please show me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can only pass one parameter through. Hence you just need to develop your own way to pass more information through. You could for example create a class and serialize it in JSON, then deserialize it at the other end. JSON serializers and deserializers are widely available in .NET and JS, this shouldn't be much of a problem at all.

Or if the data is really simple, e.g. 2 numbers, you could do 1#4, and split via the hash at the other end.

Comment: Thanks Adam for your reply. That is exactly what I am doing. I create a object literal in javascript and then in C# I desearlize the arg.